# JavaScript fetch is delayed

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch

I have an Express server waiting for my website to do something. When my site does something, a shell script should be called on the Express server. The problem is: The shell script is only run after the "confirm window" has been accepted or denied. I want the fetch to happen as soon as possible. I wouldn't even need to get anything from the Express server, I just want to signal Express to run the shell script as soon as possible.

I have this code on the website:

```
messaging.onMessage(function (payload){

    fetch("http://localhost:9000/testAPI")
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(res => console.log("something:" + res));


    var r = confirm(callingname + " is calling.");
    if (r == true) {
        window.open(payload.data.contact_link, "_self");
    } else {
        console.log("didn't open");
    }
});
```

I have this code on the backend:

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

router.get("/", function(req,res,next){
    const { exec } = require('child_process');
    exec('bash hi.sh',
        (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            console.log(stdout);
            console.log(stderr);
            if (error !== null) {
                console.log(`exec error: ${error}`);
            }
        });
    res.send("API is working");
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Your best option is probably [to avoid `confirm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm#notes). Use something like [SweetAlert](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) instead.

Comment: The `fetch` call itself is not delayed. The request is fully performed (the server receives the request) and only _then_ the `confirm` dialog opens, at least on Firefox. Upon receiving the request, the server executes your shell script as the server is completely independent of the browser. Look into your network logs, both on your server and in your browser. Does the request really not happen at all until after the confirm dialog is closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`confirm()` is blocking, and you only have a single thread. This means `confirm()` will stop the world for your application, preventing `fetch()` from doing anything.

As the simplest possible fix, you can try delaying the moment when `confirm()` is invoked. This would allow `fetch()` to get the request out.

```
messaging.onMessage(function (payload) {
    fetch("http://localhost:9000/testAPI")
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(text => console.log("something:" + text));
    
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (confirm(`${callingname} is calling.`)) {
            window.open(payload.data.contact_link, "_self");
        } else {
            console.log("didnt open");
        }
    }, 50);
});
```

Other options would be to put `confirm()` into one of the `.then()` callbacks of fetch, or to use a non-blocking alternative to `confirm()`, as suggested in the comments.